# How to make PHPStorm collapsing all methods/functions on file open?

Tags: php, user-interface, editor, phpstorm

How to make something like this? (all methods collapsed by default without any hotkeys)

[image: collapsed methods]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Solution found (File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding

[image]

Comment: Ok I think I see that you enabled the 'Method bodies' setting, but how did you use this setting to get the methods to all fold? A shortcut? menu button?

Comment: @Dimitry K. how to use it now?

Comment: @Black did you look at this page -
 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-folding.html ?

Comment: @Andrew. just hit all the checkboxes you fit necessary, for me PHP function and method bodies were enough.

Comment: What is the checkbox for the comments above PHP functions (shown in green in the OP image)? The ones included in `/** */`. Where you sometimes declare what `@params`the function uses and what it `@returns`. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 180):

This works for me: **CTRL SHIFT numpad -**

It also collapses the class... but then just manually re-open the class by clicking the + and the methods are folded.

And then you can re-open all methods with **CTRL SHIFT numpad +**

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-folding-commands.html

Comment: Windows: ctrl + +/- will expand or collapse *individual* methods

Comment: For me, using this way when I close and re-open file everything re-open.

Comment: For macOS:   `shift` + `command` + `-`

Answer (score 51):

You don't need to change anything in the settings like Dmitry suggested.

Simply do <kbd>⌥⌘⌨ *</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> -- That's OPTION+CMD+NumPad *, then 1.

If you're on Windows, it's CTRL+SHIFT+NumPad *, then 1.

Comment: Awesome! This is a very nice-to-know tip

Comment: nice, been looking for this for a while

Comment: best information in this year

Answer (score 32):

I'm using ubuntu,

the command is

-> **CTL, SHIFT and MINUS** ( this will collapse **the whole class including all methods** )

-> **CTL, PLUS** ( will expand **the class** but all methods should be collapsed )

-> **CTL, SHIFT and PLUS** ( will expand **the whole class including all methods** )

Comment: CTRL + PLUS and CTRL + MINUS are what i need. thank you

Answer (score 8):

for windows PhpStorm 2021.1

ctrl +      expand method

ctrl -  collapse method

ctrl+shift -   collapse all method

ctrl+shift +  expand all method

Comment: this is the correct answer !! than you